# Calling function from Javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#showloader").replaceWith("<span class='iconexclaim'><img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' onclick='abc()'>Retry</span>");

function abc() {
alert("abc");
}
```

The above code is replacing the html with selected element object, but when I click on retry it is showing function is not defined.

Comment: Where did you you defined your method?

Comment: your code works good for me, can you elaborate your error

Comment: @zan It is showing function is not defined

Answer (score 2):

you need to bind the click on the span to the document, this code will help you on that.

```
$("#showloader").replaceWith("<span class='iconexclaim'><img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' >Retry</span>");

    $(document)
            .on(
                    'click',
                    '.retry-btn',
                    function() {
     alert("I am here") ; 
    }) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the `abc()` inside your head tag or on body load, it will work:

```
function abc() {
    alert("hi");
    $("#showloader").replaceWith("<span class='iconexclaim'><img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' onclick='abc()'>Retry</span>");
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    abc();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jw83q9ta/3/)**

Comment: Please comment the reason for downvote, whoever it is. It is recommended also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that function code block somewhere (above it) before you call `.replaceWith` or manipulate the dom.

Comment: this is like demo what i actually calling is the funciton iteself in which I'm manipulating the DOM.                                                                                         function sam() {alert("abc");$("#showloader").replaceWith("<span class='iconexclaim'><img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' onclick='sam()'>Retry</span>");}

Comment: If that function is already inputted to the JS parser, you can do `innerHTML` or manipulate the dom until the world ends and the function will work.  See Brijesh's post, essentially what I just already said. Call the function BEFORE replacement or dom manipulation :)

Comment: I want to call the function in which I'm manipulating the DOM. What I Said already.
function sam() {
alert("abc");
$("#showloader").replaceWith("<span class='iconexclaim'><img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' onclick='sam()'>Retry</span>");
}

Answer (score 0):

Please Try like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">             </script>
       <script> 
           $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#showloader").replaceWith("<span class='iconexclaim'> <img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' onClick='abc()'>Retry</span>");

               });
        function abc(){
            alert("abc");
          }

       </script>


  </head>
    <body>
       <div id='showloader'>helloo world</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Why my point has down please give me the well explanation behind this ?